# Assigning a Pointer the value of another pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to assign the value of fileOrDir to the value of copyFileOrDir.  I want copyFileOrDir to be equal to the value of fileOrDir, not point to the same  address.  I thought it would be copyFileOrDir = *filrOrDir but I get errors.  below is my code:
(fileOrDir gets its value from a command line argument)

```
char *fileOrDir = (char *)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
char *copyFileOrDir = (char *)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
copyFileOrDir = *fileOrDir;
```

Comment: Note: [You should never cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 5):

Pointers point to a block of memory. If you set one pointer equal to another, you end up pointing to the same block of memory. If you actually assigned two different blocks, you should never want to then set one pointer to the other - you will be unable to free the memory.

Most likely you intend to do a `memcpy` which allows you to copy the contents of one memory block to another:

```
memcpy(void* destination, const void* source, size_t numberofbytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to assign the value of fileOrDir to the value of
>   copyFileOrDir.

You don't assign the value of a variable to the value of another variable. That's wrong to say. You assign a value to a variable. Think of a variable as a memory location. Also don't cast the result of `malloc`. That's not useful and can lead to bugs. Now let's come to your code snippet.

```
// don't cast the result of malloc

char *fileOrDir = malloc(25 * sizeof(char)); 
char *copyFileOrDir = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
```

The following statement

```
copyFileOrDir = *fileOrDir;
```

tries to assign the object pointed to by `fileOrDir`, which is of type `char`, to `copyFileOrDir`, which is of type `char *` -  a different type. This is an error. Also, by assigning `copyFileOrDir`, you lose the handle on the memory allocated by `malloc` causing memory leak. If you want to copy the buffer pointed to by `fileOrDir` to the buffer pointed to by `copyFileOrDir`, you should use `memcpy`.

```
memcpy(copyFileOrDir, fileOrDir, 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused about pointers and values.  You said you want the "value of copyFileOrDir to be equal to the value of fileOrDir."  But the value of fileOrDir is just a pointer to a block of dynamically allocated memory that happens to be 25 bytes (assuming sizeof(char) is one byte) in size.

What you really want is for copyFileOrDir to point to a block of memory that is an exact copy of the memory pointed to by the value of fileOrDir.  You can do this with `memcpy`.

`char *copyFileOrDir = malloc(25*sizeof(char));
memcpy(copyFileOrDir, fileOrDir, 25*sizeof(char));`

Also, I should point out that `copyFileOrDir = *fileOrDir;` makes no sense.  In that case you are dereferencing `fileOrDir` (i.e. getting the value at the address pointed to by `fileOrDir`, which is a `char`) and assigning it to `copyOfFileOrDir` which is a `char *`.  In other words, you are assigning a `char` to a `char *`.

Comment: Please don't cast the result of `malloc`. See link by Paul R in comments above. And usually it is a good idea to write `pointer = malloc(num_elements * sizeof *pointer);` this makes sure that if you change your mind about the type of `pointer`, your `malloc` still works. Good defensive coding technique.

Comment: @Floris Yeah, I didn't want to completely rewrite the OPs code.  I mean really, there's a ton wrong with it so why nitpick.  He didn't bother to check the return value on malloc either, and therefore I didn't bother to include that in my response.

Comment: @Floris Then edit your comment instead of posting another comment.